# Best portable way to connect from within a pod in a local dev kubernetes cluster to docker compose service

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, cluster-computing

I'm setting up a local development environment for a cloud native app where the idea is once in production up in Google Cloud, I'll be using Cloud SQL (managed cloud service) for data persistence. While I'm developing my application locally, I am using a local cluster with KinD, and would like my containers there to be able to reach a couple of external services outside the cluster (in this case PostgreSQL) and I'm doing it this way to keep dev/prod parity.

I have Postgres running locally using docker compose alongside my cluster, and while I can reach it already using the host's (my computer) IP + exposed port from within my pod containers, this is not very portable and would require every team member to configure their host IP to get their local environment working. I would like to avoid this.

Is there a better solution? Thanks.

Comment: Create a PostgreSQL deployment in kubernetes is not a option? The only thing will change for the application is the database host. You could use a service for you database and use the service dns as your database host.

Comment: @rabello i am trying to maintain as much parity between local and prod, and I am currently leaning towards using a managed sql instance in the cloud, so not within my k8s cluster. i am already providing the sql IP to my deployments via environment variables managed by Infrastructure as Code with Pulumi. i think grabbing the first IP returned by `hostname -I` and using that as the env value could work.

Comment: So in fact, what you need is to dynamically pass the SQL IP to your pods? If yes, this is the best way, make your application read a env variable, and them you can define your `envs` in the pod spec.

Answer (score 0):

I might have just written a blog post which could help...

https://medium.com/google-cloud/connecting-cloud-sql-kubernetes-sidecar-46e016e07bb4

It runs the Cloud SQL Proxy as a sidecar to the application. This way, only the deployment yaml would need to change with the `--instances` parameter for the Cloud SQL proxy to change from your local Postgres instance to the connection string for the Cloud SQL instance. You'll also need to sort the service account file in the deployment (covered in the blog post) so that you have the right permissions from your k8s deployment in GKE to access the Cloud SQL instance.

Comment: That definitely is an interesting article and I bookmarked it, but it doesn't seem to address my issue. During local development I am not using Cloud SQL